# Using Excel Spreadsheetdata to import ( ,move and resize) shapes into Visio

Tags: excel, vba, visio, function-call

I'm a little stuck at the moment. I try to use excel data to import and move/resize shapes into visio.
I have a running gui to let the user select all the things he need, but the code did not run properly.
My current plan (amongst many) is to use a sub in the visio file to handle movement and resize of the shapes. So excel will only call that macro and hand over all the needed information.

The visio sub will then copy (importing of images failed, so atm I need a db sheet with all available images, properly named to identify the needed image) the image to my map page and then will resize the image and position it properly.

I allready tried several approaches arround mapPage.Drop() or mapPage.Import(), but that doesn't work for some reason I don't understand.

So, now I have my CreateTile function

```
Public Sub CreateTile(x As String, y As String, lWidth As String, lHeight As String, sTile As String)
    Dim dbPage As Visio.Page
    Dim mapPage As Visio.Page
    Dim srcShape As Visio.Shape
    Dim newShape As Visio.Shape
    
    Set dbPage = ActiveDocument.Pages("DB")
    Set mapPage = ActiveDocument.Pages("Map")
    Set srcShape = dbPage.Shapes(sTile)
    
    srcShape.Copy
    mapPage.Paste
    
    Set newShape = mapPage.Shapes.ItemFromID(mapPage.Shapes.Count)
    newShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).FormulaU = x & " mm"
    newShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinY).FormulaU = y & " mm"
    newShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormWidth).FormulaU = lWidth & " mm"
    newShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormHeight).FormulaU = lHeight & " mm"
End Sub
```

which will be called by my Excel function

```
sParam = CStr(Replace(Round(coords(0), 4), ",", ".")) & ", " & CStr(Replace(Round(coords(1), 4), ",", ".")) & ", " & CStr(ufMain.tBoxWidth.Text) & ", " & CStr(Replace(Round(CDbl(101.6 * ufMain.tBoxWidth.Text / 67.7333), 4), ",", ".")) & ", " & CStr(sTile)
                    
Debug.Print ("CreateTile " & sParam)
visDoc.ExecuteLine "CreateTile " & sParam
```

the Debug.Print will return `CreateTile 40, 34.642, 40, 60, shapeName01`.
The Replace() in sParam is due to having a , instead of a . as separator, which is no problem for excel, but for Visio. So I decided to transmit only strings and handle the rest on the visio site.

On the Visio side used

```
Sub test()
    CreateTile "40", "34.642", "40", "60", "hexForestBroadleaf00"
End Sub
```

to test if the code on Visio side works and it really works like a charm.
I even could call test() from Excel side via `visDoc.ExecuteLine "Test "` multiple times, so I assume I have a problem with transfering the parameters to visio, but I don't get my error.

I am very happy for any help, because solving this problem will save me a real bunch of time. :)

Comment: Try `& Chr(34) & CStr(sTile) & Chr(34)` in `sParam` and see if that works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Vince No, that doesn't help.

Comment: @Community I'm looking for a way to call a visio makro with parameters out of an excel file.

Comment: Are you getting an error when trying to run `ExecuteLine` from Excel? I made a simple test scenario and it works fine.

Comment: Excel dont have `ExecuteLine` method, there is [same method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run) named `Run`.

Answer (score 0):

> @Community I'm looking for a way to call a visio makro with parameters out of an excel file.

You must add prefix `ThisDocument.` for call Visio macro from Excel. This line looks like

```
visDoc.ExecuteLine "Thisdocument.CreateTile ""1"", ""2"", ""3"", ""4"", ""5"""
```

Comment: OP stated that the `test` macro worked without specifying `ThisDocument`, and it worked fine for me in testing when using subs in `Module1` without specifying.

Comment: As I understand OP successfully run this code without `ThisDocument` only when call this code from Visio. May be I wrong. But my code can be started from Excel application

Comment: @Vince, you are right. For **Module1** it works without specifying. May be problem in code line `sParam = CStr(Replace(Round(coords(0), 4), ",", ".")) & ", " & CStr(Replace(Round(coords(1), 4), ",", ".")) & ", " & CStr(ufMain.tBoxWidth.Text) & ", " & CStr(Replace(Round(CDbl(101.6 * ufMain.tBoxWidth.Text / 67.7333), 4), ",", "."))`